# Use ECDH key with ECIES

Tags: crypto++

In Crypto++, I'm trying to use a public key generated by ECDH to encrypt a message with ECIES. Is that possible? The key is stored in a SecByteBlock. I've tried two options: 1) reading the bytes directly via StringSource; 2) creating an Integer and encoding it to BER, then trying to decode it in the public key. None of these options worked, both generate a BER format exception.

What might I be doing wrong? Is there any other way to set the ECIES encryptor public key's bytes directly?

Thanks!

Comment: The public key in ECIES is a point on an elliptic curve, not just an integer. There are elliptic curves where points can be represented by a simple integer, but those are not the default curves like the sec256p one. Your question sounds like you might misunderstand what ECIES is: ECIES *contains* the ECDH-like agreement for a temporary symmetric key. If you want to perform ECDH yourself, and just want key symmetric key derivation and symmetric encryption, you need to plug these two parts yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry for the beginner's questions, but I really do not know very much about ECC. So, assuming I have the curve and a previously ECDH generated public key with this curve, how could I use it to encrypt data? I do realise in a regular basis I'd use the private key or the agreement, but I do need to encrypt with the public key, this is a small step in a custom protocol (not designed by me) I'm trying to conform to.

Comment: If you have an ECC key-pair (suitable for use with ECDH), you can use this keypair also with ECIES. It contains of a private key which is just a plain big integer, but the public key is a point on the curve, which typically is a pair of X and Y coordinates of that point. If you have a BER representation of that point, you should be able to decode it in the public key. Having an integer as ECDH public key sounds plain wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wondering, what I was actually trying to do was this... Suppose that at some point a key pair was generated in the following way:

```
ECDH<ECP>::Domain domain(some_curve);
SecByteBlock prv(domain.PrivateKeyLength()), pub(domain.PublicKeyLength());
domain.GenerateKeyPair(AutoSeededRandomPool(), prv, pub);
```

Later, given just the raw (bytes) representation, if you need to load these keys for encryption, you could do:

```
auto& params = domain.GetGroupParameters();
ECIES<ECP>::PrivateKey prv_key;
ECIES<ECP>::PublicKey pub_key;
prv_key.Initialize(params, Integer(prv.begin(), prv.size());
pub_key.Initialize(params, params.DecodeElement(pub, true));
```

And then create Encryptor/Decryptor as needed:

```
ECIES<ECP>::Encryptor encptor(pub_key);
ECIES<ECP>::Decryptor decptor(prv_key);
```

Anyway, thanks for the help in the comments, it put me in the right direction to find the answer!

Comment: `prv_key.Initialize(params, Integer(prv.begin(), prv.size());` - you should not use the shared secret directly. You should digest the shared secret to extract the entropy. Use something like [HKDF](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/hkdf.h). Also, you might want to take a look at IPSec. IPSec is a bit more disciplined than TLS; and it uses the same technique to extract the entropy.

Comment: @jww `prv` is not a shared secret. It's the private key of a static DH key-pair. The line as quoted is fine. Of course you are right you should not use the (EC)DH shared secret directly, and HKDF is a good suggestion. Indeed, ECIES internally does use a key derivation function, and IIRC the default is a hash-baed one.